# Sealing of non-circular cross sections

Tags: seals, coupling

I have to mate two sections of something that could be reasonably approximated by a tube, though the material is stainless steel, and the cross-section is very non-circular, so I cannot use an o-ring. The walls are thin and the exterior must remain flush, so a flange/gasket is also out.

**Are there established methods for pressure sealed mating of non-circular cross-sections?**

Worth mentioning I will be able to compress the two pieces via internal screws.

The diagram below shows some examples of what I might expect appropriate solutions may look like:

[image: Diagrams of possible mating geometries]

The left most is how the parts are now, with a flat mating surface. This would provide a terrible seal.  The right two are possible solutions, but I would really like some precedence to justify my design.

Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  To address the comments, the **wall thickness is 1/32"**. I will post a picture of the cross section below. Only the channels are pressurized against near vacuum in the internal volume and in the exterior.  The gauge would be at **max ~10 bar**. There is no limitation on roughness of the channels. I cannot weld them because being able to open and close the part is a critical design feature.  Gaseous Nitrogen is the fluid.

Sealing between the channels is not necessary.

[image: Cross-section of part]

Comment: o-rings can adapt to non circular shapes, as long as you give the groove shape several o-ring-width's of radius. rectangular o-ring-like gaskets exist too. face seals can be any shape if you have axial force and something to contain the seal in place laterally...  can you show thickness, pressure/ vacuum range, and more part detail regarding how it's non circular?

Comment: a sleeve around it or a non-standard 3-D gasket

Comment: Copper gasket___

Comment: So weld it. Stainless can be welded.

Comment: Adding to PeteW's comment:  first, you seem to claim there's not enough thickness for a gland, so why do you think a shaped O-ring (easily obtained from major manufacturers could be used?

Comment: In any case,  you can't get useful advice unless we know things like the  pressure levels involved, allowable non-smoothness (mating ridge, e.g.) on the inside, which affects the Reynolds Number,  types of fluids being transported, etc.  **and wall thickness**

Comment: It is very difficult to visualize the mating surface giving the images you've posted. However you can seal almost anything by adding a smooth surface on one part, and a matching o-ring groove on the opposite part. The groove path does not need to be circular, it just need to maintain a certain minimum bend radius. You can buy o-ring material on a spool and glue the ends together to make an o-ring of any length.

Comment: If you can provide strong, and even pressure to the mating parts, it is possible to create an airtight seal with metal on metal. One part would have a smooth surface, and the other would have very small ridge that squishes slightly as the parts are clamped together (like an o-ring).